# lein - how to use a downloaded library

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Let's say I find a cool clojure library like https://github.com/clojurewerkz/buffy

Now I want to use it. And it only lives on github.

How do I do this? I would love a full start to finish hello world example.

I've read about compiling it as a jar and using that, or using :dependencies in my project.clj but so far no examples have been complete, and I'm new.

For example in python I'd `git clone` the repo into the root of my working tree and any file could just say `import buffy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just learned this five minutes ago. I wanted to use the [clojure-csv](https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv) library, here's what I did using [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/)

1. Make a new leiningen project

   `lein new app csvtest`
2. Now I have a folder called `csvtest/`. In the `csvtest/project.clj` file, edit the dependencies section to add the clojure-csv github path and a version. I'm not quite sure how the versioning works to be honest:

   ```
   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                  [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "2.0.1"]]
   ```
3. Now run `lein deps` to automagically download any unresolved dependencies for your project

   ```
   $ lein deps
   ...
   Retrieving clojure-csv/clojure-csv/2.0.1/clojure-csv-2.0.1.pom from clojars
   ...
   ```
4. Now edit `csvtest/src/csvtest/core.clj`. Make it look like this:

   **Edit:** (Based on sveri's comment I changed `:use closjure-csv.core` to the `:require` line)

   ```
   (ns csvtest.core
     (:gen-class)
     (:require [clojure-csv.core :refer [parse-csv]]))

   (defn -main
     "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
     [& args]
     (println (parse-csv "1,2,3,hello,world")))
   ```

   You have to add the `(:require [clojure-csv.core :refer [parse-csv]])` line to your `ns`, and in main it calls `parse-csv`, one of the functions provided by the library. From reading, it looks like `:use` is depreciated in favor of `:require`.

   **Note:** For anyone coming from python (like me), it looks like doing `:use clojure-csv.core` is akin to `from closure_csv import *`, which is bad practice in python as well. And `(:require [clojure-csv.core :refer [parse-csv]])` is like `from clojure_csv import parse_csv`
5. Run the project with `lein run`. My output was

   ```
   $ lein run  
   ([1 2 3 hello world])
   ```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Please dont use ":use" for your imports, you can find more best practices here: https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide

Answer (score 1):

You can download/use it from Clojars.

Clojars link:
https://clojars.org/clojurewerkz/buffy

To use it with [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/), add this to your dependencies(on project.clj file):
`[clojurewerkz/buffy "1.0.0-beta4"]`

After that, you can run `lein deps` from your project root folder in order to download dependencies.

To use dependencies directly from Github repos, you can check out this: https://github.com/tobyhede/lein-git-deps

Answer (score 1):

Using lein (which is Clojure's build tool) you have a project.clj file. if you do `lein new project-name` you get a new project named "project-name", with a project.clj file in it. look at that file, you will see a :dependencies entry in it as in this example:

`:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]`

all you must do to include buffy, is look at their github site, and find out which version to use, then you add it to the :dependecies list:

`:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                [clojurewerkz/buffy "1.0.0-beta3"]]`

now you can simply do `lein deps` which will download the dependencies and once you written your code `lein run` to actually run it.

read a little about [lein](http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2010/11/26/a-leiningen-tutorial.html) and check out its [sample project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj) file to get a better understanding of how you should use clojure.